# firefox "crypto.subtle.exportKey" spki not working

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I am using javascript to en/decryption clientside and php serverside. In php i am using openssl functions for aes and rsa encryption. Since newly released ver. 7.3.0 of php it is possible to use ecdh public+private key derivation with openssl_pkey_derive.

My problem is that the crypto.subtle.exportKey to public spki pem key in firefox seems to be broken. The key is exported, but the result can't be used! According to https://diafygi.github.io/webcrypto-examples/ it should be posible, but the result from key export don't work! Chrome and safari works without problems. Edge can't even generate ec keys!

The question is: Where do i report this problem?

Comment: The bug tracker is at [https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). There is [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1083765) from 4 years ago, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Dimitry Thank you, I vil report it there.